# Injecting jQuery where Prototype exsists - noConflict()

Tags: prototypejs, inject, jquery

I'm using webkit only. I need to inject jQuery into a page that already has prototype loaded. I'm using this code to load jQuery. (you can try in console)

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.js');
s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

I get an error with just the code above.

How can I use noConflict() on load. If I put the following code after injecting the jquery script, I still get an error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.noConflict();
  // my thing here
});
```

This also throw an error:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
  // my thing here
});
```

Comment: I [updated my ansewr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461147/injecting-jquery-where-prototype-exsists-noconflict/6461340#6461340) to reflect the fact that you need to use an `onload` handler for your jQuery script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
  // my thing here
});
```

You can then use $j for any jquery $

Comment: I get the error: `jQuery is not defined`. I think the problem is that when jQuery loads, it clashes with Prototype and doesn't even put jQuery on the page. Do you think it is because **prototype version 1.3.1**? That is a little old.

Comment: That doesnt sound like a conflict.  It sounds like jquery is not being loaded in your html hesder properly.  Can you paste how you are loading jquery?

Comment: I'm going to close this question. **psynnott** correctly guessed that jquery is not loading at all, so I'm going to give him the answer and upvote others for your efforts. The page in question is running on old copy of prototype (1.3.1), and is crashing jquery before it can even load, and before I can get to use jQuery at all, regardless of noConflict() and $.

Comment: @skymook: It has nothing to do with `prototype` crashing it. It has to do with the fact that you're trying to use `jQuery` before it is loaded. This happens when you load a script from within another script. The original one needs to finish executing before the one you're loading can execute. As such, you can't use jQuery in the original script. You'd have the same problem even if you didn't load `prototypejs` at all. I updated my answer to show the solution to the problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am loading the jquery content through prototype ajax. please advice me.

Comment: @user2003356 Please start a new question for that.  In the question provide information on your problem, preferably with code samples.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Because you're loading the script from another script, you should put the `jQuery` code you need to run in a callback to a load event for your script:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.js');
s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);

   // Place your code in an onload handler for the jQuery you're loading
s.onload = function() {

    jQuery.noConflict(); // release jQuery's hold on "$"

    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

      alert( $.fn.jquery );
   });
};
```

Another solution would be to *not* use this method of loading jQuery. Just hardcode your `<script>` element, and the code will run in the expected synchronous manner:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict(); // release jQuery's hold on "$"

      // do this with ready() -------v------ and the "$" will be available inside
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

      // $ is safe for jQuery inside this .ready() callback
      alert( $.fn.jquery );
    });
</script>
```

---

**Original answer:**

Do this:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.js');
s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);


jQuery.noConflict(); // release jQuery's hold on "$"

  // do this with ready() -------v------ and the "$" will be available inside
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

  // $ is safe for jQuery inside this .ready() callback
  alert( $.fn.jquery );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It is a great solution if my original question was accurate.

Answer (score 1):

$ is the alias/shortcut for jQuery (as well as prototype).  NoConflict basically releases control of the $ shortcut, so that once called, the other library has control of it.  Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // my thing here
});
```

Comment: The reason I am using noConflict() is because prototype is using $. However, jQuery is not loading, it just goes right into an error. `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'function (object) { return Object.extend.apply(this, [this, object]); }' of object [object Object] is not a function jQuery.each.jQuery.fn (anonymous function)jquery.js:(anonymous function)jquery.js:`

Answer (score 1):

Here, you use `$` first and then use `jQuery.noConflict()`, the problem is that you've (wrongly) assumed `$` is jQuery before you've set up the no conflict:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.noConflict();
  // my thing here
});
```

Here, you've done the opposite. You've done the no conflict bit first, good, but then continued to use `$` to access jQuery, which will no longer work (as a direct result of the `noConflict()` call):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
  // my thing here
});
```

Combining your two efforts you end up with the following. I've also added a `$` to the `.ready` line so that inside the `ready` function you *can* still use `$` as your jQuery reference.

```
jQuery.noConflict(); // stops $ being associated with jQuery
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // use long-hand jQuery object reference to call `ready()`
  // my thing here
});
```